# Iterating over json objects in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array called mainarray which has multiple json objects.

```
mainarray:Object
  >key1: Array[30]
  >key2: Array[20]
```

I want to do sorting on Array[30] and Array[20].
I am trying to do it like this:

```
mainarray.forEach((arrayinner)
{
  //sort
});
```

But I am getting error : **as Cannot read property of undefined.**

How can I iterate ? and also key names are dynamic ,I cant hardcode it and start iterating/

Comment: please use the word *array* as variable name only for arrays, and not for objects. it makes the life easier.

Comment: you need to put an arrow after the passed argument like `mainarray.forEach((arrayinner) => { // sort })` in fact for a single argument you don't even need the parentheses and do like `mainarray.forEach(arrayinner => { // sort })` and then the idea behind inline arrows is to cut the code short. So no point in using long variable names and you can reduce your code more like `mainarray.forEach(a => { // sort })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the function keyword for a valid callback declaration.

```
mainarray.forEach(function (arrayinner)
//                ^^^^^^^^
{
  //sort
});
```

But the problem is deeper:

You need to get the keys and to iterate over them and take the propery value to apply a sort

```
Object.keys(mainarray).forEach(function (key) {
    mainarray[key].sort();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each(mainarray, function(key,val){
  val.sort((a,b) => {return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0});
});
```

since the `val` is an array aka an object. Its reference will be shared inside of the callBack function. So affecting that array inside callBack will affect the original array.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jjvuvjwn/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the array of keys to iterate over

```
Object.keys ( mainarray ).forEach( function( arrayinner ){
  arrayinner.sort();
});
```

if the all the keys inside `mainarray` may not have `Array` value, then you can check before sorting

```
Object.keys ( mainarray ).forEach( function( arrayinner ){
  Array.isArray( arrayinner ) || arrayinner.sort();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by looping over the properties of the object itself and sorting the arrays they contain, something like this:

```
for (var key in mainarray) {
    if (mainarray[key] === Array)
        mainarray[key].sort();
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/26gk4h9b/)

Note that by default `sort()` only uses basic alphanumeric sorting logic. If you need anything more complex you would need to implement that yourself.